# onClick is not working in stateless functional component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, components

I tried to call a function inside onClick in stateless functional component but it's not working. It works when I use statefull component with class Clock extends React.Component and onClick={this.play}.

I have st like this: (edited below)

```
const Clock = function() {

  let second = 0;
  let minute = 25;

  const play = function() {
    if (second == 0) {
      second = 59;
    }
  }

  const style2 = {margin: "10px", fontSize: "30px"};
  let min = ('0' + minute).slice(-2);
  let sec = ('0' + second).slice(-2);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="time-left" style={style2}>{min}:{sec}</div\>
      <div id="start_stop" style={style2} onClick={play}>Icon</div\>
    <div\>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock/\>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here's my new code:

```
import React, { useState } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1" //I use "from "react" " but codepen.io autocorrect to this link

const Clock = function() {
  
  const [minute, setMinute] = useState(25);
  const [second, setSecond] = useState(0);

  const play = function() {
    if (second == 0) {
      setSecond(59);
    } else if (second < 60 && second > 0) {
      setSecond(second - 1);
    }
  } //I intend to use setInterval later to call this function every sec to make a countdown clock

  let min = ('0' + minute).slice(-2);
  let sec = ('0' + second).slice(-2);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="start_stop" onClick={() => play()}><i class="fas fa-play"></i></div>
      <div id="time-left">{min}:{sec}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Clock/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, i made an answer instead of a comment.

i see you're missing a parenthesis and react uses the **class** keyword, so you need to use className=

```
// above code...

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="start_stop" onClick={() => play()}><i className="fas fa-play"></i></div>
      <div id="time-left">{min}:{sec}</div>
    </div>
  )
} // <= here missing this

ReactDOM.render(<Clock/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

for the cdn of react i'd use a link in the html like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
```

so the entire html is like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React CDN Usage</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

you can see the example here: https://codepen.io/forest-black/pen/eKVMQW

ps: if you're learning react, i highly suggest to use stackblitz or codesandbox, they have a better code linting and code editor

Comment: Yeah I think the problem is about the react link. 
When I use `ReactDOM.render(<Clock/>,document.getElementById("root"));` with links to react 18.2 (which is suggested by codepen now) my elements aren't renderred neither. I have to copy a link to react 16.7 from other's work to render my elements

Comment: i highly suggest that you use something else instead of codepen, since code linter on that (the thing that tells you the error) is not the best. as stated on my answer you should check out some options like codesendbox / stackblitz to understand and work with react. anyways most probably is the react version that gives you problem, to solve that you need to use another ide which shows you errors in your code

Comment: Thank you I'll try using codesendbox and update asap

Comment: Everything is fine when I use StackBlitz. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

React uses states to detect variable changes. the code works but the DOM doesn't change because react doesn't know that the variable value has changed, to let react know you need to use 'useState':

reference: [react documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState)

like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Clock = function () {
  const [second, setSecond] = useState(0)
  // let second = 0;
  const [minute, setMinute] = useState(25)
  // let minute = 25;

  const play = function () {
    if (second == 0)
      setSecond(59);
  }

  const style2 = {margin: "10px", fontSize: "30px"}

  let min = ('0' + minute).slice(-2)
  let sec = ('0' + second).slice(-2)

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="time-left" style={style2}>{min}:{sec}</div>
      <div id="start_stop" style={style2} onClick={play()}>Icon</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

To update a variable you use the set function, in this case 'setSecond' / 'setMinute'

also watch out the closing tags of the jsx/html elements

plus:
if you meant to call the function by clicking and not when the page renders, you need to change the code like this:
with an anonymus funciton, so it doesn't get triggered on page render but only when clicked

```
onClick={() => play()}
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But as soon as I assign this const `const [second, setSecond] = useState(0)`  all element in my `return() {}` disappear from the screen and cannot be renderred. I'm sorry if my question seems stupid since I'm new here

Comment: there's no such thing, everyone start from somewhere. anyways, if you could provide a new snap of your code, i could check it out and see what we are talking about!

Comment: Thank you so much. I've just edited the code above, please check it out

Comment: so, i see that you're missing a closing parenthesis } in the last line before 
ReactDOM.render(<Clock/>,document.getElementById("root"));

plus i'm not sure you should use that link for importing react, id use this one: in the html:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

Comment: i made a new answer for the sake of space and clarity ahahah

Comment: Yeah i did include it in my code. There's no such syntax errors and codepen doesn't show any warning error signs. The elements in my `return() {}` only show up when i delete 2 lines which assign 2 const `minute` and `second` with `useState`. So I think the problem is about the react link.

Also, when I use `ReactDOM.render(<Clock/>,document.getElementById("root"));` with links to react 18.2 (which is suggested by codepen now) my elements aren't renderred neither. I have to copy a link to react 16.7 from other's work to render my elements

Comment: I dont understand concept of react and how its version affects my code

Comment: have you tried to do as this link: https://codepen.io/forest-black/pen/eKVMQW
add the script tag to your html ?

Comment: Yes i did, the different is your link use class-extends component (it work when I use this component too). But when I tried to use functional component as my code above, all elements aren't renderred

Comment: Everything is fine when I use StackBlitz instead of Codepen. Thank you so much

Comment: no worries, good luck with the learning process!

Answer (score 0):

Your `second` and `minute` variables will re-render to the default value each time a render is triggered by a change, such as your click. So you should  make use of the `useState` hook and perhaps `useEffect` to reduce the value of your minutes and seconds which is what I assume you're trying to achieve here.

Here's how I would refactor this code (Simplified - You can adapt to contain minutes as well):

```
const Clock = () => {
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(seconds > 0) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setSeconds(seconds - 1)
            }, 1000)
        }
    }, [seconds])

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id="start_stop" onClick={() => setSeconds(59)}>Icon</div>
        </React.Fragment>

    )
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But as soon as I assign this const `const [second, setSecond] = useState(0)`  all element in my `return() {}` disappear from the screen and cannot be renderred. I'm sorry if my question seems stupid since I'm new here

Comment: There's no stupid questions, don't worry!

Can you post your new refactored code? I'm happy to take a look and see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've just edited the code above. Please take a look

Comment: In the code you've posted, you're missing a closing `}` bracket after your `return()` statement. Let me know if this works after fixing.

Also just a PS. You should always ensure that you use `className` instead of `class` when using React to avoid render warnings.

Comment: Yeah i did include it in my code. There's no such syntax errors and codepen doesn't show any warning error signs. The elements in my `return() {}` only show up when i delete 2 lines which assign 2 const `minute` and `second` with `useState`. So I think the problem is about the react link.

Also, when I use `ReactDOM.render(<Clock/>,document.getElementById("root"));` with links to react 18.2 (which is suggested by codepen now) my elements aren't renderred neither. I have to copy a link to react 16.7 from other's work to render my elements

Comment: I dont understand concept of react and how its version affects my code

Comment: Everything is fine when I use StackBlitz instead of Codepen. Thank you so much